# trouble with getting my mod_rewrite rules to run

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been trying several variations to get my server to redirect - but all seem to fail. :(

This is my url:

```
"meaty-monster-bikes.zz-reviews.com/monster-bikes/p1c9.html"
```

Now the data I want to collect in variables is the portion after

```
"meaty-monster-bikes.zz-reviews.com/"
```

so in this case I want "monster-bikes" and "p1c9"

Then using the collected variables the server can redirect to:

```
"zz-reviews.com/index.php?p=1&c=9&k=monster-bikes"
```

I have thried this in my **.htaccess** file:

```
Options +SymLinksifOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[\.0-9-a-z]+/([-a-z]+)/p([0-9]+)pg([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?p=$2&c=$3&k=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

I also tried :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[.+].zz-reviews.com/([-a-z]+)/[.+]$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^[\.0-9,:\/-a-z]+p([0-9]+)c([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?p=$1&c=$2&k=%1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

As far as I can see, both should work, 
but neither do.

This is the webpage:

http://zz-reviews.com/index.php?p=1&c=9&k=monster-bikes

If you click on the Category "Monster Bikes"

You will see this url:

"http://meaty-monster-bikes.zz-reviews.com/monster-bikes/p1c9.html"

The htaccess does not properly redirect.

Can anyone see my mistake ?

Thanks .

.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/([a-z]+)(\d+)([a-z]+)(\d+)\.html$ index.php?$2=$3&$4=$5&k=$1 [L,NC]
```

This is the Rule you need - when you go to the url

> meaty-monster-bikes.zz-reviews.com/monster-bikes/p1c9.html

You will redirect (behind the scenes) to this url

> meaty-monster-bikes.zz-reviews.com/index.php?p=1&c=9&k=monster-bikes

**Explaination**:

`^([^./]+)` - starts after the com the first arg (`$1`) take all characters until `/` - this will take the string "monster-bikes"

`/` - the / character of the url

`([a-z]+)` - follow by abc letter (you can change it if there are other strict) this will take "p" (`$2`)

`(\d+)` - follow by number - this will take "1" (`$3`)

`([a-z]+)` - follow by abc letter - this will take "c" (`$4`)

`(\d+)` - follow by number - this will take "9" (`$5`)

`\.html$` - ends with string ".html"

Redirect it to index.php with the assembled parameters:

`index.php?$2=$3&$4=$5&k=$1` = `index.php?p=1&c=9&k=monster-bikes`